# jQuery Menu Management (functions) - Open and Close

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, toggle

I have a jQuery powered CSS3 menu system which I got from here (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/ ) I'm using this impressive menu as part of my site navigation however I have run into a problem, I want to display more than one of these menus as I have a lot of links.

The jQuery code is as follows (note the #dl-menu2 showing that I'm using two menus not one)

```
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu({
                animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-2', classout : 'dl-animate-out-2' }
            });
                    $( '#dl-menu2' ).dlmenu({
                animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-2', classout : 'dl-animate-out-2' }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My question is how can I make a menu 1 close when menu 2 is opened? At the moment when you click menu 1 the menu opens up but won't close when you click on menu 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dlmenu code is interesting, once initialised you can call it again with a string for the function to execute. As such you could change the `index.html` from the git repository ([here](https://github.com/codrops/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/blob/master/index.html)) to automatically open the menu by changing `$(function(){...}` to:

```
$(function() {
    $('#dl-menu').dlmenu();
    $('#dl-menu').dlmenu("openMenu");
});
```

You can also use the above to close a menu. However I couldn't find any mechanism to add listeners to the dlmenu code.

So the best solution is to add your own and utilise the following:

```
    $('#dl-menu').dlmenu("closeMenu");
```

The `'#dl-menu'` is a reference to the id of your menu div, so you can specify whatever menu you wish to close by the id.

The tricky part is firing the listener when the other menu is clicked. This is complicated by the fact that the logic in dlmenu is clearing and setting the click on $(body) whenever a menu is opened. Easiest approach is to add an id to the button. The current logic in `index.html` is:

```
<button class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>
```

It has no id so add one for each menu you have defined:

```
<button id="dl-menu1-button" class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>
```

Then you can change the `$(function() {...}` to do the following (presuming you have added another menu and changed the id's such that you have a `dl-menu1` and `dl-menu2`):

```
$(function() {
    $('#dl-menu1').dlmenu();
    $('#dl-menu2').dlmenu();

    $('#dl-menu1-button').on("click", function() {
        $('#dl-menu2').dlmenu("closeMenu");
    });
    $('#dl-menu2-button').on("click", function() {
        $('#dl-menu1').dlmenu("closeMenu");
    });
});
```

I've tested the above by getting a clone of the git repository, adding the id's and changing the init as above. Worked how you have asked.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Many many thanks for this very comprehensive response.